# AngularJS e2e Testing with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am attemping to get the last row of a ng-repeat(ed) table via protractor to test and ensure the object I just created in a previous test run shows up.  I have gotten as far as getting all of the text of the row but cannot seem to figure out through trial and error how to get each column of the last row as part of the array so I can verify each piece and then in the last column I have buttons to click which will be the next step.

The code I have so far is:

```
var elems = element.all(by.repeater('alert in alerts'));
elems.last().then(function(elm) {
    console.log(expect(elm.getText()).toMatch('/testRunner/'));
});
```

As mentioned above, the expected output/output I want to check against is 'textRunner' and instead I get the entire row of text as such:

```
testRunner testing the runner 5 minutes No View Edit Enable
```

**EDIT**
Here is my final code:

```
var rows = element.all(by.repeater('alert in alerts'));
rows.last().then(function(row) {
    var rowElems = row.findElements(by.tagName('td'));
    rowElems.then(function(cols){
        expect(cols[0].getText()).toContain('testRunner');
        expect(cols[1].getText()).toContain('testing the runner');
        expect(cols[4].getText()).toContain('5 minutes');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rows = element.all(by.repeater('alert in alerts'));
rows.last().then(function(row) {
    var rowElems = row.findElements(by.tagName('td'));
    rowElems.then(function(cols){
        expect(cols[0].getText()).toContain('testRunner');
        expect(cols[1].getText()).toContain('testing the runner');
        expect(cols[4].getText()).toContain('5 minutes');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are using a [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table), and your different values are in [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td), you could check values by using the [`by.tagName` locator strategy](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#locator-strategies).

```
var rows = element.all(by.repeater('alert in alerts'));
var row = rows.last();
var rowElems = row. findElements(by.tagName('td'));
expect(rowElems.get(0).getText()).toMatch('/testRunner/');
expect(rowElems.get(1).getText()).toMatch('/testing/');
expect(rowElems.get(2).getText()).toMatch('/the/');
expect(rowElems.get(3).getText()).toMatch('/runner/');
expect(rowElems.get(4).getText()).toMatch('/5/');
expect(rowElems.get(5).getText()).toMatch('/minutes/');
expect(rowElems.get(6).getText()).toMatch('/No/');
expect(rowElems.get(7).getText()).toMatch('/View/');
expect(rowElems.get(8).getText()).toMatch('/Edit/');
expect(rowElems.get(9).getText()).toMatch('/Enable/');
```

Comment: When I use your code I get the correct columns but not the correct row, I only get the first row not the last.  Is there a way of counting the rows and using that then?

Comment: There was a bug in my code. I use element instead of elm. I change the variable names for clarity.

Comment: I get an TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'all' error

Comment: And if you use `findElements` ?

Comment: i try without using the promise api.

Comment: I needed to use the promise to get access to the text in each column but it works.  Thanks for the push in the right direction.